# How to pass $.getjson data in php, better yet using laravel's @foreach

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, laravel-4

```
$.getJSON( 'http://localhost/media_books/index.php/new_books.json?provider_id=1&limit=99&offset=1')
.done(function( json ) {
    $(tar).closest('.accordion').children('div').text(json);
});
```

I can display the [Object object] on the div which means I'm successful from getting the json data, but how can I parse it so that I can create a table using the json object.

Or better yet if there is a way to pass it to the body so that I can use laravel's @foreach.

Comment: try to dump the json using console.log(json) to display the data structure, use for(key in json){} to iterate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.getJSON( 'http://localhost/media_books/index.php/new_books.json?provider_id=1&limit=99&offset=1')
.done(function( json ) {
//to find out object properties
for(var i in json)
{
  alert(i);
}
  //then you can access object property like json.propertyName;
  //$(tar).closest('.accordion').children('div').text(json);
});
```

Comment: My json returns [object Object], not a string json so .parseJSON(json) does not work on my json

Comment: for further reference please look at [http://elegantcode.com/2009/05/04/jquery-ajax-with-class-arrays/](http://elegantcode.com/2009/05/04/jquery-ajax-with-class-arrays/)